# UDID from itune using Mac Application

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, cocoa, itunes

I am working on a mac application which will be used by 'XXXX' company's customers to register themselves, along with using their iPhone's UDID. That UDID will be added to the apple portal to generate an Ad Hoc Profile.

So here is my question:

1. Is there any way our Mac Application can talk to iphone utility(windows)/itunes(mac) and get the device UDID, as soon as they connect their device.
2. If 1st is not possible, Is there any way we can ask the user to copy their device's UDID and fill in the from. After that we can confirm that the UDID is correct or not(using any web service or somthing).

Thanks in Advance

Chahal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any supported way to use the private MobileDevice.framework to talk to the device like iTunes does.

The easiest way for a user to find their UUID is to click on the device information in iTunes and then copy and paste it.

If you are looking for a way to help automate beta testing then you might want to take a look at one of the established services like TestFlight or HockeyApp.

Comment: Hi macshome, thank you for your answer, but to create an ad-hoc provisioning profile I need UDIDs. If customers agrees to send over their UDIDs, is there any way(web service) to confirm if the sent UDID is correct or not?

Comment: I don't know of any way to pre-verify the UDID before sending the profile. Obviously the app won't work if it's wrong and they can send it again. That's how services like TestFlight work to generate IPAs that have profiles in them.

Comment: yes, true, you are right. Anyways, Thanks a lot for your answer. cheers !!